# Ajax POST to MVC Controller always erroring

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Projects/Index',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: xhr => { swal('From Error!', 'We\'ve saved your hours, thanks for your input!', 'success'); console.log(xhr) },
    success: result => swal('From Success!', 'We\'ve saved your hours, thanks for your input!', 'success')
});
```

Which, even when the status code is 200, always errors. My controller receives the `data` and does *stuff* with it, and then returns `View()`.

Here's my controller action in full:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult SetHours(HourPostRequest[] data)
{
    foreach(var item in data)
    {
        var correctModel = item.ToEngineerHours(db);
        db.EngineerHours.Add(correctModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    var eng = db.Engineers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.DomainUsername == User.Identity.Name).ID;
    var test = db.EngineerHours.Where(e => e.EngineerID == eng).ToList();

    return View(test);
}
```

The data is always intact, received fine and `View` always returns. I've added in a random `test` collection to return which is the model of my View:

`@model IList<Timesheet.Models.EngineerHours>`

I've gone into the Chrome Dev-Tools Network view and the payload is correct, response is 200 and the controller has received the data and returned `View`.

This means that my `SweetAlert2` alerts are always erroring regardless of the success status.

Can anybody spot why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the View(), which is an HTML string at the end of the day. However in your request you specify:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

which tells jQuery to expect response as a json formatted string. jQuery sees HTML and is not able to recognize it as a valid json, hence the error.

Comment: Much appreciated!